# Skip first 3 header rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form that is currently allowing input from my form in VBA into my Excel spreadsheet.  When I use the Previous button or the next button it deletes everything from a prior input into what is on the form.  is there a way to Click previous and see the previous data entered, allow editting but change to the fields when you select the previous button again?

```
Public nCurrentRow As Long

Private Sub Next_Command_Click()
    Do
        nCurrentRow = nCurrentRow + 1
        TraverseData (nCurrentRow)
    Loop Until C_C_L.Cells(nCurrentRow, 1).Value = "" Or C_C_L.Cells(nCurrentRow, 1).Value = Me.PI_Text.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Previous_Command_Click()
    Do
        nCurrentRow = nCurrentRow - 1
        TraverseData (nCurrentRow)
    Loop Until nCurrentRow = 1 Or C_C_L.Cells(nCurrentRow, 1).Value = Me.PI_Text.Value
End Sub
```

**Also Is there a way to skip the first 3 lines (headers) so the new data does not overwrite my headers?**

Comment: Are these the only 2 places where `nCurrentRow ` is used?

Comment: If you want to preserve the edited version of a record while moving back or forwards, you will need to store the edited information somewhere, maybe on a hidden "pending changes" sheet.

Comment: Yes that is the only place that nCurrentRow is coded

Answer (score 0):

You should add another button `AddRecord_Command` that will bring the set the current row to the next empty row.  In this way, `Previous_Command` will move back one record and `Next_Command` will not move past the last record.

### The code below should handle both this question and your previous question [How to update spreadsheet from VBA Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39151950/how-to-update-spreadsheet-from-vba-form)

```
Option Explicit
Private NC_C_L As Worksheet
Private nCurrentRow As Long
Private firstRow As Long

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set NC_C_L = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    firstRow = 4
    ReadData
End Sub

Private Sub AddRecord_Command_Click()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = NC_C_L.Range("A" & NC_C_L.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    WriteData
    nCurrentRow = lastRow + 1
End Sub

Private Sub Next_Command_Click()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = NC_C_L.Range("A" & NC_C_L.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If nCurrentRow < lastRow Then
        WriteData
        nCurrentRow = nCurrentRow + 1
        ReadData
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Previous_Command_Click()
    If nCurrentRow > firstRow Then
        WriteData
        nCurrentRow = nCurrentRow - 1
        ReadData
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ReadData()
    With NC_C_L
        Me.A_Text.Value = .Cells(nCurrentRow, 1)
        Me.B_Box = .Cells(nCurrentRow, 2)
        Me.C_Combo.Value = .Cells(nCurrentRow, 3)
        Me.C_Combo.Value = .Cells(nCurrentRow, 4)
        Me.F_Combo.Value = .Cells(nCurrentRow, 5)
        Me.H_Combo.Value = .Cells(nCurrentRow, 6)
        Me.I_Combo.Value = .Cells(nCurrentRow, 7)
        Me.J_Text.Value = .Cells(nCurrentRow, 8)
        Me.K_Text.Value = .Cells(nCurrentRow, 9)
        Me.Comments1_Text.Value = .Cells(nCurrentRow, 10)
        Me.Comments2_Text.Value = .Cells(nCurrentRow, 11)
        Me.Comments3_Text.Value = .Cells(nCurrentRow, 12)
        Me.PhoneNumber_Text.Value = .Cells(nCurrentRow, 13)
        Me.Address1_Text.Value = .Cells(nCurrentRow, 14)
        Me.Address2_Text.Value = .Cells(nCurrentRow, 15)
        Me.City_Text.Value = .Cells(nCurrentRow, 16)
        Me.State_Combo.Value = .Cells(nCurrentRow, 17)
        Me.Zip_Text.Value = .Cells(nCurrentRow, 18)
        Me.EMail_Text.Value = .Cells(nCurrentRow, 19)
        Me.P_Name_Text.Value = .Cells(nCurrentRow, 20)
        Me.P_PhoneNumber_Text.Value = .Cells(nCurrentRow, 21)
        Me.P_Address_Text.Value = .Cells(nCurrentRow, 22)
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub WriteData()
    With NC_C_L
        .Cells(nCurrentRow, 1) = Me.A_Text.Value
        .Cells(nCurrentRow, 2) = Me.B_Box
        .Cells(nCurrentRow, 3) = Me.C_Combo.Value
        .Cells(nCurrentRow, 4) = Me.C_Combo.Value
        .Cells(nCurrentRow, 5) = Me.F_Combo.Value
        .Cells(nCurrentRow, 6) = Me.H_Combo.Value
        .Cells(nCurrentRow, 7) = Me.I_Combo.Value
        .Cells(nCurrentRow, 8) = Me.J_Text.Value
        .Cells(nCurrentRow, 9) = Me.K_Text.Value
        .Cells(nCurrentRow, 10) = Me.Comments1_Text.Value
        .Cells(nCurrentRow, 11) = Me.Comments2_Text.Value
        .Cells(nCurrentRow, 12) = Me.Comments3_Text.Value
        .Cells(nCurrentRow, 13) = Me.PhoneNumber_Text.Value
        .Cells(nCurrentRow, 14) = Me.Address1_Text.Value
        .Cells(nCurrentRow, 15) = Me.Address2_Text.Value
        .Cells(nCurrentRow, 16) = Me.City_Text.Value
        .Cells(nCurrentRow, 17) = Me.State_Combo.Value
        .Cells(nCurrentRow, 18) = Me.Zip_Text.Value
        .Cells(nCurrentRow, 19) = Me.EMail_Text.Value
        .Cells(nCurrentRow, 20) = Me.P_Name_Text.Value
        .Cells(nCurrentRow, 21) = Me.P_PhoneNumber_Text.Value
        .Cells(nCurrentRow, 22) = Me.P_Address_Text.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I REALLY appreciate the assistance.  Unfortunately when I go to run it I get an error Run-time error '1004';  Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Did you correct the names of the controls?  I gave the controls that you named `Me.***` dummy names.

Comment: It doesn't even take me to my form I immediately get that error as soon as I click Run

Comment: When you press debug; it doesn't bring up the forms code?

Comment: OK that first error was user error.  I have a couple test ones and I put in the wrong name, oops.  Let me see what else - I am getting more errors

Comment: I think my names are messing me up.  But so far I can't get it to work

Comment: In the Next_Command - it does not like the 

lastRow = NC_C_L.Range("A" & .NC_C_L.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: I appreciate the assistance although it's not working

Comment: I enjoy helping.  I updated my answer.  There are two areas that have `.NC_C_L.Rows.Count`.  The first dot needs to be removed `NC_C_L.Rows.Count`

Comment: Yeah I removed those.  I don't know what's wrong with it.  I re-read the code and flip some things and I finally got it to run again but then the Next & Previous & Create New wouldn't work.  So I don't know

Comment: I Em'd what I saved into my Test document